# Weight a column in SolR 8.9

Tags: search, solr, lucene

I'm trying to have to a query on all fields, and then weight in function of the field using solr and lucene. For the search i'm using a all field in which I copy all the values of the document and set it up to default field.
Fore example, if we search a database about books with the word "John" it could be found in the author name and in the title.  In that case I would like that the title weight more, without having to write a specific title, so by boosting the title column itself. If possible being able to write that directly in the config (solr or managed schema) would be the best.
I think pf woudl do the job, but my interniship supervisor told me that he would like to only use lucene and not dismax

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can add additional terms to your query - i.e. add `title:John^5` as well as your plain `John` query - that way you'll get those that have hits in `title` as well higher in your result.

Comment: Yea, I saw this, but I was wondering if I could boost only the field and not a word on the field. But if there is no other way I guess I'm gonna see with my supervisor, but thanks anyway.

Comment: That would be what the edismax handler is made for.

Comment: Yea I guess we won't have another choice

Comment: Yea, I guess we won't have anoher choice